# How to find angle $v$ in a rectangular diagonal

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am unable to find a way to find the angle $v$ (in degrees) in a rectangular diagonal. 
Here's what I have:

- Opposite: $15.1$ m
- Hypotenuse: $23.5$ m
- Adjacent: $x$
- $v$ = measure (in degrees) of the angle opposite to the 'Opposite' side

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: $\sin v=\frac{15.1}{23.5}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Remember that $\sin(v) = \frac{O}{H}$.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the hint, however, I am not sure, afaik, if you have v and need H it is very straight forward, but if you have O & H - how do you really get V, since calculator shows = 0.6425531915, which I am not so sure about, since it does not seem correct.

Comment: The sine of the angle $v$ is equal to the Opposite over the Hypotenuse. So you need to work out $\frac{O}{H}$ with your calculator. Then remember that the sine of $v$ is equal to that number. A $sin^{-1}$ or 'arcsin' function will let you put in that number to get $v$.

Comment: sin−1(0.6425531915) = 39.9824691 ~ 40 degrees, the final answer is correct, but have I done these steps correctly? Thanks!

Comment: We know that $\sin(v) = \frac{O}{H}$. Then $\sin^{-1}(\sin(v)) = \sin^-1(\frac{O}{H})$. Because $\sin$ and $\sin^{-1}$ are inverse functions of each other, they cancel each other out (NB: this is only an intuition, and is not always technically true). So $v = \sin^{-1}(\frac{O}{H})$. If you did that, then you did it correctly.

Comment: Hmm, here's how I did it: 

Sin v = 15.1/23.5
=> sin^-1(15.1/23.5) ~ 40 (39.982)
v = 40

Comment: Yeah, that's the right idea.